# Get a list of non-contiguous values

Tags: node.js

In LevelUP you can return a single value by doing

```
db.get('foo', function (err, value) {
  // .. handle `value` here
})
```

Imagine you have an arbitrarily long array of non-contiguous keys:

```
var lotsOfKeys = ['skajhda', 'asdasdsasd', 'sfsfsdfsdf', 'dssdfdsf'];
```

What is the best way to return the corresponding list of values from the leveldb database, given that `db.get` is asynchronous, and that `lotsOfKeys` can be of length 1 to n?

Is there some clever way to do chaining of `.gets` to return the list the values for the keys contained in `lotsOfKeys`?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the best way to handle this would be to just use an async helper library. Here's an example using [map-limit](http://npmjs.org/package/map-limit/):

```js
var map = require('map-limit')
var keys = [
  'skajhda',
  'asdasdsasd',
  'sfsfsdfsdf',
  'dssdfdsf'
]

// limits to batches of 20 db.gets
map(keys, 20, function(key, next) {
  db.get(key, next)
}, function(err, results) {
  if (err) throw err

  results = keys.reduce(function(memo, key) {
    memo[key] = results[key]
    return memo
  }, {})

  results['skajhda']    // the result of db.get(keys[0])
  results['asdasdsasd'] // the result of db.get(keys[1])
})
```